# rsync --size-only -avbr fails to create backup file

Tags: linux-mint, rsync, nemo

I've recently discovered `rsync` and started to use it. I want to compare files based on `filename` & `filesize` only. If both match, then skip, if different size, then keep dest version (renamed) and copy from source.

I gave it a try and it failed to create backup file with options `rsync --size-only -avbr` for one file with same name and different size, just replacing it (source was NTFS, destination exFAT). I created test environment on `tmpfs` drive, first with dummy files - backup was created, then actually copied that two files and again backup copy was created with `~` at the end.

I did several tries with original locations to be sure that issue persists, including omitting `a` flag with thoughts that maybe on non Linux file systems `rsync` cannot properly read some properties. And creating small file with name `12345678` and small text type content - still same issue - just replacement.

Why `rsync` does not keep original file in my case? I have two guesses: either it still somehow uses timestamp if `backup` option is added to `size-only` and just copying files from non-Linux file systems to `tmpfs` mangled some important details or `rsync` cannot be expected to work correctly with non-Linux native file systems.

System Linux Mint 19. NTFS and exFAT mounted `type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096,uhelper=udisks2)`

Answer (score 0):

The "issue" was not with `rsync` but with Nemo file manager that for some reason considers files with `~` at the end created as backup as hidden and does not show them (shows with `show hidden files` option). Strange IMHO behavior as hidden files are those starting with dot, as e.g. stated here https://askubuntu.com/questions/232649/how-to-show-or-hide-a-hidden-file.

Comment: maybe the question is not worth to keep, but I could not decide for myself to delete it.